# Controlling Phonon via command line?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, kde, pulseaudio, phonon

My onboard audio card has analogue and digital outputs parallel, where I do connect them to my speakers and an amplifier. Now every time I want to switch where the sound goes I have to long way via `Kmix` to reach `Phonon` configuration:

`Settings -> Audio Setup -> Audio Hardware Setup`

and then choose proper `Sound Card` and `Profile` (and sometimes optionally `Sound Device` and `Connector`).

Is there any way how I could do this via command line? I want write me a script, but not sure through which utility I can control these settings?

Comment: Fedora 26, 2017, and KDE insists in changing by itself the *Audio Hardware Setup* config with a nonworking device despite the fact that I change it back on each session...

Answer (score 1):

**About Phonon and cli**

There is a wish in the KDE Bug Tracking System: http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=212091 (Bug 212091 - Configure phonon from command line)

but it seems that the Phonon is not available (not yet ? - last marking 2011-03-04) through the command line.

**Phonon links**

- http://phonon.kde.org/
- http://userbase.kde.org/Phonon
- http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Phonon/Introduction
- http://community.kde.org/Phonon